# Append custom string in User agent for IE Only

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, registry, bho

I am creating toolbar usign the BHO.And in that I want to modify the user agent string in IE as follow:

current string : Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0) 
Require string : CustomName, Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)

Here I want to add custom Name before the Mozilla/4.0 text. So how can I do it?
What changes I need to make in the registry "User Agent" key or I need to make changes in some other registry key?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option would be via registry - see for details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#UARegistry

Comment: Thanks for reply. I looked given link previously also. but I can't find in that how add string before the Mozila/4.0 text.

Comment: you are welcome... please don't forget to upvote/mark as accepted any answer the was of help

Answer (score 0):

In your dialog/window that hosts the web browser (IWebBrowser2/CWebBrowser2/etc) you just need to override OnAmbientProperty.  It is a virtual method part of CWnd.

```
BOOL CMyLoginDlg::OnAmbientProperty(COleControlSite* pSite, DISPID dispid,
   VARIANT* pvar)
{
   if (dispid == DISPID_AMBIENT_USERAGENT)
   {
      CString strUserAgent("CustomName, Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)");

      pvar->vt = VT_BSTR;
      pvar->bstrVal = strUserAgent.AllocSysString();

      return TRUE;
   }

   return __super::OnAmbientProperty(pSite, dispid, pvar);
}
```

That should do it!